# I want to keep my trailing zeroes when using DecimalFormat

Tags: java, number-formatting, decimalformat

The code below is my attempt to convert my three doubles into a format where they have four decimal places always (because I need to print them with four decimal places for what is meant to be a simple assignment), even if all the numbers after the decimal point in the original double are 0  - as in any whole number. I figured I might be able to use the setMinimumFractionDigits() method to prevent DecimalFormat from eliminating trailing zeroes - but it doesn't do the job: "3.0" still gets printed out instead of what I want: "3.0000". I realise that below my instances of this setMinimumFractionDigits() method are literally doing nothing.

(Numbers whose decimal places aren't all zeroes aren't a problem; the code is working as I want it to for them.)

........ Is there an easy fix? There may be; I don't understand very well the methods I'm using here.

```
           double  mean = mean(numbers);
            double variance = variance(numbers, mean);
            double sd = sd(variance); 
            DecimalFormat meanFormatted = new DecimalFormat("#.####");
            meanFormatted.setMinimumFractionDigits(4);
            mean = Double.valueOf(meanFormatted.format(mean));
            DecimalFormat varianceFormatted = new DecimalFormat("#.####");
            varianceFormatted.setMinimumFractionDigits(4);
            variance = Double.valueOf(varianceFormatted.format(variance));
            DecimalFormat sdFormatted = new DecimalFormat("#.####");
            sdFormatted.setMinimumFractionDigits(4);
            sd = Double.valueOf(sdFormatted.format(sd));
```

Comment: Replace the hashes with zeroes.

Comment: that doesn't work, Joe C

Comment: `DecimalFormat meanFormatted = new DecimalFormat("#.0000");`

Comment: That doesn't work either, Scary Wombat

Comment: `System.out.printf(".%4f .%4f .%4f",mean,variance,sd);`

Comment: Noam, you could does not seem to store the result of `format` as a String.  A `double` by itself does not have any intrinsic formatting, see my answer below for correct usage

Comment: Noam, did you consider my answer at all?

Answer (score 1):

see this usage

```
   double d = 12.3;
   DecimalFormat meanFormatted = new DecimalFormat("#.0000");
   System.out.println (meanFormatted.format (d));
```

Answer (score -2):

Found a solution:

```
      double mean = mean(numbers);
        double variance = variance(numbers, mean);
        double sd = sd(variance); 
        Formatter transform = new Formatter();
        Formatter transform1 = new Formatter();
        Formatter transform2 = new Formatter();
        transform.format("%.4f", mean);
        transform1.format("%.4f", variance);
        transform2.format("%.4f", sd);
        System.out.printf("\nMean = %s\n", transform);
        System.out.printf("Variance = %s\n", transform1);
        System.out.printf("Standard deviation = %s\n", transform2);
```

Comment: -1, this solution is already in the comments (besides the other posted solution actually works). You should really consider other answers and comments before posting the answer to your own question.

Comment: First of all, your answer is an almost replication of [This comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43649914/i-want-to-keep-my-trailing-zeroes-when-using-decimalformat/43650094#comment74347706_43649914). If that is the answer to your question, you should ask them to post it as an answer. Nevertheless, the other answer also completely solves your problem (and fixes the bad usage in your code)

Comment: nah, i had to import another class for my solution... the comment didn't mention that.